# Azure CLI throwing OutOfRangeInput error while uploading build artifact to the blob storage in the release pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to deploy a static webpage with Azure DevOps and Azure Blob storage. From the release pipeline, I am trying to upload the build artifact with Azure CLI. But it is throwing **OutOfRangeInput** error.

`az storage blob upload-batch --account-name  'accountname' --account-key 'accountkey' --destination ‘$web’ --source './web'`

I have a small storage-account name and with lowercase letters.

[image]

Comment: Can you share the YAML you use in DevOps?

Comment: Hi @SumitPaul,

How are things going? Is the suggestion in my answer helpful to you? Please check with the suggestion. Any progress, feel free to tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Azure DevOps should make some clear documentation on how the tasks differentiation exists among ***AzureCLI@0*** vs ***AzureCLI@1*** vs ***AzureCLI@2***. So that anyone facing this kind of problem can understand what is their requirement and which task version he/she should use.

The solution was to change the task version, and it worked out of the box. Just downgraded the task version from ***AzureCLI@2*** to ***AzureCLI@1***. Other than that please keep in mind the @Bright Ran-MSFT's answer first.
[image: change task version]

Comment: Hi @SumitPaul, Glad that you have solved the problem, and thanks for sharing your solution. I recommend that you can mark your answer as the solution of this topic, this may be very helpful to other people who are looking for a solution for the similar questions.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the resource names, especially the **Blob Name**, contain any special characters.

If the resource names contain some special characters, percent-encode them using **`UTF-8`** (preferred) or **`MBCS`**, then try the upload again.

Or you also can try to set a new name without any special characters.

To view more details, you can see "[**Naming and Referencing Containers, Blobs, and Metadata**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/naming-and-referencing-containers--blobs--and-metadata)".

Comment: Hi, in my question I have already mentioned that my blob storage name consists of all lowercase letters. I have found a solution, I will post it, so in future, it might help others.